# String not evaluated correctly in my program

Tags: java

I'm new to JAVA programming and right now I'm facing a strange case. I set the confirmation variable to the type of String , it will hold the user input. When the user type "yes" The program should create a new user, but it didn't . Instead, it rise the false alarm "Process is canceled by user". It seems the convirmation variable didn't evaluated correctly. Any advice guys. thanks.

This is my code (it's pretty simple though):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreateUser {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String confirmation;

        System.out.println("Create new user");
        System.out.print("Enter first name : ");
        firstName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter last name : ");
        lastName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Are you sure?");
        confirmation = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println(confirmation); // this line is to make sure that the variable value is "yes"

        if(confirmation == "yes")
        {
            Users newUser = new Users(firstName, lastName);
            System.out.printf("User %s %s has been created\n", firstName, lastName);
            System.out.println("Total active users now is :"+Users.getRegisteredUsers());
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Process is canceled by user");
        }

        input.close();

    }
}
```

And this is the output :

```
Create new user
Enter first name : fin
Enter last name : fin
Are you sure?
yes
yes
Process is canceled by user
```

Comment: use equals for string comparison. "yes".equals(confirmation)

Comment: Compare equality of objects (`String`s, `Integer`s and others) using `equals` method, not using `==`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
if (confirmation.equals("yes")) {
}
```

instead of

```
if(confirmation == "yes")
```

`.equals()` compares the values of 2 strings. `==` compares the memory reference to see if they point to the same object.
[Reference article](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/)

Comment: you should explain why so the OP learns, not just post the answer.

Comment: Or "yes".equals(confirmation) to avoid NPE

Comment: This is solve my problem. But, why we cannot use "==" for this case. I made a simple program to test the "==". I made String a = "yes" then evaluate it using :
if(a == "yes")? System.out.println("OK") : System.out.println("not OK");
and it evaluated correctly. Why did it fail with my confirmation variable? would you explain it? thanks

Comment: `.equals()` compares the values of 2 strings. `==` compares the memory reference to see if they point to the same object.

Comment: hmm.. it's still lil' bit confusing for me... :)
But thanks for your solution.